# AJAX / PHP server issues

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

Okay so, I have made a cPanel like file manager. The main difference is I have all the source code for it and I can manipulate it at my leasure. My issues is my save function for my text editor. I am using [ACE-editor](http://ace.c9.io). I have no problem getting the value of the editor but submitting it via, aJax request has been hell for me.
The save function is the following.

```
if(isset($_POST['text'])  && isset($_POST['location'])){
   $location = $_POST['location']; //this also contains the file name 
   $contents = fopen($location, 'w') or die("can't open file");
   $submitedData = $_POST['text']; // this contains the editor's text
   fwrite($contents, $submitedData); 
   fclose($contents); 
}
```

The aJax request is the following

```
$.ajax({
  url: "edit.php",
  type: 'POST',
  data: {
    'text': e.getValue(),
    'location':$('#saveValue').val()
  },
  success: function () {
    errorReport("File has been saved!");
  },
  error: function (){
    errorReport("Failed to save file");
  }
});
```

Some need to know things

- editor = `<div id="e"></div>`
- SaveValue = `<input type='text' id="saveValue" value="<?=
  $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].$_GET['dir'];?>">`
- `var e = ace.editor("e");`
- `$_POST['test'] = e.getValue();`
- `$_POST['location'] = ('#saveValue').val();`
- `$_GET['dir']` is the current directory you're in e.g.
  `/path/to/files/index.php/`

but it does not include the path before the like /public_html so /home/user/www/public_html is hidden

So, now that you know the basics of how it works. when I do my ajax call on Ace's keyboard shortcut `Alt + S` It submits my ajax request. My issue is when it submits it the request times out. Like it doesn't know where to submit it and it is frustrating me because I am getting NO error back any where. These functions have worked in the past but now they are timing out and failing to save ANYTHING. I am hoping that I made a mistake in my code somewhere.

**So my question is:** Why would ajax appear to timeout on a request like I seem to be getting, and how can I fix this problem? ( I submitted the page to try to see how long I would have to wait for it to get a response it took >15 minutes to anything back from the page, and that was a time out error.)

Comment: A suggestion: do not pass `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` in HTML, but rather access that variable from within the PHP function to save. No need to expose that information to your users.

Comment: A suggestion: does anything change if you pass the full URL to edit.php, e.g. `url: "http://www.yourserver.com/path/to/edit.php",`

Comment: To your first comment, the only people who would have access to this page are those users who are suppose to be there. Other wise no one else will see it so the user will konw what the value of `$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']` is anyway. TO your second comment, sadly nothing changes when I put the full URL.